# RDD and PipelinedRDD type

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am bit new to PySpark (, more into Spark-Scala), Recently i came across below observation . When i am creating RDD using parallelize() method the return type is **RDD** type. But when i am creating RDD using range() method it is of type **PipelinedRDD** . For example:

```
>>> listRDD =sc.parallelize([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
>>> print(listRDD.collect())
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> print(type(listRDD))
<class 'pyspark.rdd.RDD'>

>>> rangeRDD =sc.range(1,8)
>>> print(rangeRDD.collect())
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> print(type(rangeRDD))
<class 'pyspark.rdd.PipelinedRDD'>
```

I checked how both rdds are constructed and found :

1)Internally both are using parallize method only.

```
>>> rangeRDD.toDebugString()
b'(8) PythonRDD[25] at collect at <stdin>:1 []\n |  ParallelCollectionRDD[24] at parallelize at PythonRDD.scala:195 []'
>>> listRDD.toDebugString()
b'(8) PythonRDD[26] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:53 []\n |  ParallelCollectionRDD[21] at parallelize at PythonRDD.scala:195 []'
```

2)The PipeLineRDD is a subclass of RDD class that i understand.

But is there any generic logic when it will of type PipeLineedRDD and when it will be of RDD type?
Thanks All In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sc.range` is indeed calling `parallelize` method internally - it is defined [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/b517f991fe0c95a186872d38be6a2091d9326195/python/pyspark/context.py#L491). You can see that `sc.range` is calling `sc.parallelize` with xrange as input. And `sc.parallelize` has a separate code branch when called with xrange input type: it calls itself with the empty list as argument and then applies `mapPartitionsWithIndex` [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/b517f991fe0c95a186872d38be6a2091d9326195/python/pyspark/context.py#L523) which is the final output of `sc.parallelize` call and `sc.range` call in turn. So you can see how first regular object is created similarly as you do with `sc.parallelize` (though object is an empty list), but final output is the result of applying mapping function on top of it.

It seems that the main reason for this behavior is to avoid materializing the data which would happen otherwise (if input doesn't have len implemented, it's iterated over and converted into list right away).

Comment: HI Alexander.. Thanks for replying .Just bit more detail adding to above.
1.  Here i am using  Open source dist of Spark 2.4.+ binary. (Even all other dist like Databricks , cloudera ,zaloni, MapR also uses same open source with  adding extra feature .eg. Databricks added delta lake but still uses Same Spark Code internally  That is the reason when they will rediredct you Apache Spark Page when You look for any APi specific help.)
2) I am aware of lazy evaluation and Resiliant nature of RDD. I don't think my point is related to these .

Comment: 3) Both **range()** and **parallelize()** method uses **parallelize** internally .. Check **toDebugString** output. 
4) On either case, the only difference i am seeing is the way of providing data to spark . Except that , for both cases we are using almost same Python Collection .and same action . So its no where spark storing data.

Comment: I'm not sure why you mention different distributions in your comment. I'm talking about the most usual open source Apache Spark. But you are right and my link was on SparkSession's `range` function which creates DataFrame rather than RDD.  And you're also right that `sc.range` is calling `parallelize` - and the reason why result is different is because as you can see there is a separate code branch for xrange type as input for `parallelize` function [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/b517f991fe0c95a186872d38be6a2091d9326195/python/pyspark/context.py#L491).

Comment: So internally for xrange type `parallelize` is calling itself with empty list and then applies `mapPartitionsWithIndex` thus different type of output. (and `sc.range` is just calling `sc.parallelize` with xrange as input).

Comment: I guess the comment about multiple distributions was inspired by my sentence regarding which version of spark you're using. I kind of had in mind version as in 2.4.5, 3.0, etc. Anyway, I guess the mystery of different types is solved now. Thanks for correcting me. I've updated my answer too.

Comment: I missed this document . Thanks for putting the link